# ValueError: Found unknown categories while calling cross_val_score

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I'm working on the Titanic Dataset as my first Kaggle Project. But I get this User Warning And I'm trying to find out how to get rid of it.

So I made two Preprocessing sub-pipelines:

```
num_pipeline = Pipeline([
('imputer', SimpleImputer( strategy='median')), 
('scaler', StandardScaler()) ])

cat_pipeline = Pipeline([
('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='missing')),
('onehot', OneHotEncoder()) ])
```

My selected features for building the model are :

```
numeric_features = ['Age', 'SibSp', 'Parch', 'Fare']
categorical_features = ['Pclass', 'Sex',  'Embarked']
```

My Preprocessing Pipeline is :

```
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
transformers = [
    ('num', num_pipeline, numeric_features),
    ('cat', cat_pipeline, categorical_features)
])
```

In my final Pipeline I add a classifier:

```
clf = Pipeline([
('Preprocessor' , preprocessor),
('Classifier', DecisionTreeClassifier()) ])
```

Then i call cross_val_score to evaluate the model, and this is when I get the User Warning:

```
cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=3, scoring="accuracy")
```

> ValueError: Found unknown categories ['Missing'] in column 2 during transform
> UserWarning,
>
> array([       nan, 0.70403587, 0.74774775])

My guess is the cross_val_score gets the first fold WITHOUT the 'Missing' category and then test it on another WITH the 'Missing' category.Hence the Error.
So I tried to drop the rows with the missing values in 'Embarked', but still get the error which is weird.

Answer (score 4):

I just incurred in this myself, and then I realized that it makes no sense to run `OneHotEncoder` separately for each fold of the cross-validation.

The [docs for ColumnTrasnformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#columntransformer-for-heterogeneous-data) say

> Processing your data before passing it to scikit-learn might be problematic for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. Incorporating statistics from test data into the preprocessors makes cross-validation scores unreliable (known as data leakage), for example in the case of scalers or imputing missing values.
> 2. You may want to include the parameters of the preprocessors in a parameter search.

So it is correct you put `SimpleImputer` and `StandardScaler` in the `ColumnTransformer` which goes directly in the `Pipeline` fed to `cross_val_score`: they will be refitted indipendently for each fold, avoiding using information from the validation set.

However `OneHotEncoder` should be run in a separate step, before feeding the data to `cross_val_score`, i.e. `X_train` should already contain one-hot variables rather than categorical ones.

In this way not only will you avoid this Warning (due as you already mention to seeing a class in the validation set not present in the fold's training set) but also you will keep the one-hot variables consistent, as they should be. In other words you don't risk the one-hot variables get ordered or named differently for each fold.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you did the following:

1. Clean the dataset i.e fill all na/missing values for all columns
2. Filter and drop NaN rows i.e all values NaN rows

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Yes as shown above I used Imputer to deal with missing values.

Comment: that's weird, did you check your data again to be double sure that there are no missing/na or string values present in your data? from the error message it seems like the data is causing this.

Comment: Here is what I think: for categorical data and exclusively for the feature "Embarked" there is 2 missing values. Those 2 missing values I replace them with "Missing" (its the " ['Missing'] " category mentioned in the Error ).

Comment: so you're replacing with a string ('Missing')? and you're feeding this data containing string value to your model? If you're, then you can't do that, you need to preprocess all the string (categorical, etc.) and convert them into numerical values. There're many ways handling these string data, you can check out sklearn's [`OneHotEncoder()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html), [`LabelEncoder()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html). May help you resolve your issue.

Comment: Totally agree! 
But after i change the null to 'Missing' i use OneHotEncoder().
It works when I fit the model (= clf.fit(X_train, y_train) works perfectly), the problems accurs when I call the cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=3, scoring="accuracy")

Comment: I see, It's however strange that the `.fit()` is working perfectly whereas the `cross_val_score()` is giving error. Nonetheless, I know somehow that the problem is with the data for sure as the error is suggesting. I wish I could get ahold of your code may be in google colab or something, then I could take a look at it myself. It's hard to guess around without a proper look and information.

Comment: Here's Link to the notebook in colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/166JVzJP4qMs8OLmNjyCWfWWj7GwsHJ2Q?usp=sharing

Comment: seems like you're using local data, thus I can't access the data (`pd.read_csv(r"gender_submission.csv")`) doesn't work because it can't find the data.